# Why does my client accepts 2 connections?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm on Windows. I have a server with a blocking socket that should accept a client at a time and allow it to do some operations on a buffer. When the first client ends it should serve the second and so on. However it seems to accept two connections. It allows only the first client to do the operations and when the second one disconnects it serves the second. A third client can't connect.

Server

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''
PORT = 5552

buffer = []

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error:
    sys.exit()

sock.listen(1)
client, client_addr = sock.accept()

#OPERATIONS
```

Client

```
import socket
import sys

def connect(sock, ip, port):
    try:
        sock.connect((ip, port))
    except socket.error:
        sys.exit()

def send(sock, message):
    try:
        sock.sendall(message)
    except socket.error:
        return -1

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'localhost'
port = 5552

try:
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
except socket.gaierror:
    sys.exit()

connect(sock, ip, port)

#OPERATIONS
```

Answer (score 1):

From `listen.__doc__`:

```
    Enable a server to accept connections.  The backlog argument must be at
    least 0 (if it is lower, it is set to 0); it specifies the number of
    unaccepted connections that the system will allow before refusing new
    connections.
```

Your server is willing to accept another client because you've told it to do so.

Change your backlog argument on:

```
sock.listen(1)
```

to:

```
sock.listen(0)
```

and your server will stop allowing that second connection to wait to be accepted.

Comment: It behaves exactly the same. If I increase the backlog argument it accepts more connections, but if I set it to zero it's the same.